# How to use contractAbi.Unpack to parse raw log data into a log type struct

Tags: go-ethereum, abi, golang, decentralized-exchange

I am following the guide [here](https://goethereumbook.org/event-read-erc20/) but I am not able to replicate what is being done in the guide.

```
var transferEvent LogTransfer

err := contractAbi.Unpack(&transferEvent, "Transfer", vLog.Data)
if err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
}
```

First of all the Unpack function [only takes two parameters](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/abi#ABI.Unpack), and using UnpackIntoInterface doesn't work for me neither.

I use the following code to try and feed the raw bytes into my struct using [this Tx](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x1ce0e3868b5bc7dc78d8a4061af9dc5b945d34416b514f5b73e75eabc322e054):

```
contractAbi, err := abi.JSON(strings.NewReader(string(uniswap.UniswapABI)))
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }

            fmt.Println(txReceiptLogs[i].Data)

            eLog, err := contractAbi.Unpack("Transfer", txReceiptLogs[i].Data)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal("Error unpacking into interface: %v", err)
            }

            fmt.Println(eLog)
```

This actually works for me and prints out:

```
[491956807]
[301904282124331099]
[491956807]
[1007639403678612]
```

Which is correct. However, when I try to do the same for the Uniswap Sync event which has the following hash:

"0x1c411e9a96e071241c2f21f7726b17ae89e3cab4c78be50e062b03a9fffbbad1"

I get an empty array, or more precisely a struct filled with two empty values.

```
{<nil> <nil>}
```

What I would want to know is how to get the unpack function also working for the Uniswap Sync event in the logs ([I use this ABI](https://etherscan.io/token/0x4d42fd2fe2eb1e4c7eec64272a1f715dce0ea535#abi)). And if an updated example could be provided for the Unpack function in general that would be very nice as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the UnpackIntoInterface() method which takes three parameters

```
event := struct {
    Key   [32]byte
    Value [32]byte
}{}
_ = contractAbi.UnpackIntoInterface(&event, "ItemSet", vLog.Data)
fmt.Println(string(event.Key[:]))   // foo
fmt.Println(string(event.Value[:])) // bar
```